# construct a path in $\Bbb{R}^n$ with specific derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If we want a curve $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to \Bbb{R}^n$ to have  $\gamma(0) = x$, and $\gamma'(0) = b$. It suffices to take $\gamma(u)= x + u \cdot b$.

At the same time, I have a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$( $f: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$).

I would like to consider a path $\gamma$ such that $f\circ\gamma(t)$ satisfies

$$f\circ\gamma(0) = f(x) \qquad (f\circ\gamma)'(0) = f'(x)\cdot b \qquad (f\circ\gamma)''(0) = \sum_{ij} a_{ij} (\partial_i \partial_j f(x))$$

Is this possible?

**Note:** it is not the case that $a_{ij} = c_i c_j$  for some $c \in \Bbb{R}^n$

Comment: What is the meaning of the symbol $\gamma''(0)$?

Comment: It is the second derivative of $t\mapsto \gamma(t)$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Well, shouldn't $a$ be a vector? I mean, the derivative of the curve is itself a curve, so the second derivative should also be a curve on the same space...

Comment: a∈ℝn×n ..... don't quite follow

Comment: Yes you are right. @JoãoRamos

Comment: In this case, $x + bt +\frac{at^2}{2}$ is your desired curve

Comment: I just edited the question. Now I think it makes sense

Comment: Yesssss, sometimes in mathematics, in order to get the right answer, you only have to understand if your problem is well posed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that $f\circ\gamma'$ is shorthand for $(f\circ\gamma)'$, and similarly  $f\circ\gamma''$ is shorthand for $(f\circ\gamma)''$. Assume $x=0$.

It's about the function
$$\phi(t):=f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\ .$$
By the chain rule one has
$$\phi'(t)=\sum_k\partial_k f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\>\gamma_k'(t)$$
and
$$\phi''(t)=\sum_{k,\>l}\partial^2_{kl}f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\gamma_k'(t)\gamma_l'(t)+\sum_k\partial_kf\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\>\gamma_k''(t)\ .$$
In particular, for $t=0$ we obtain
$$\phi'(0)=\nabla f(0)\cdot b\ ,$$
where $b:=\gamma'(0)$, and
$$\phi''(0)=Hf(0).(b,b)+\nabla f(0)\cdot c\ ,$$
where $H$ denotes the Hessian of $f$ at $0$ and $c:=\gamma''(0)$. Now you want
$$\phi''(0)={\rm trace}(AH)$$
for a given matrix $A$. The scalar equation
$$\nabla f(0)\cdot c={\rm trace}(AH)-Hf(0).(b,b)$$
has solutions $c\in{\mathbb R}^n$ whenever $\nabla f(0)\ne0$. Pick any such $c$ and consider the curve
$$\gamma(t):=t\>b+{t^2\over2}\>c\qquad(-\epsilon<t<\epsilon)\ .$$